# jQuery won't work if externally loaded elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, object, embed

I'm importing an external php file into a different php file.

External file:

```
function featured($featured) {
echo '<button id="switch">CLICK ME!</button>';
echo '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="427" width="700" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=blahblah" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=blahblah&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object>';
}
```

Main file:

```
<div id="div">
</div>

<script>
    var xmlhttp;

    function loadXMLDoc(url, varString, cfunc){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    var channel = window.location.search;
                    if(channel.length>0)
                            varString = channel.substring(1);
        xmlhttp.send(varString);
    }   
    loadXMLDoc("external.php", "channel=", function(){ 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    });
</script>
```

The loadXMLDoc function works perfectly fine, I can see the elements and interact with the button and play the video in the object tag. However when I apply the following code to either the external file or the main file I get no interaction whatsoever.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#switch" ).click(function() {
  $( "object" ).attr("data", myNewURL);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', "#switch", function() {
        $( "object" ).attr("data", myNewURL);
    });
});
```

Your `#switch` element was added after the `.click()` method, so it didn't have the event attached to it. In this case, **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** will helps you to attach the click event to this newly added `#switch` element.

Answer (score 0):

use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

**on()** Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click', "#switch", function() {
        $( "object" ).attr("data", myNewURL);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [***delegate***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click","#switch",function(){
   //some operation
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for the external loaded elements